# sp_executesql not returning results in the same way as normal query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sp-executesql

I saw in SQL when executing a query using sp_executesql it takes MINUTES to process it, while i run the same query in a normal way declaring the parameters runs in 2 seconds.

sp_executesql

```
EXEC Sp_executesql 
N'SELECT TOP (27) [ARSalesPrice].[RecordID], [ARSalesPrice].[PriceType], [ARSalesPrice].[CustPriceClassID], [ARSalesPrice].[CustomerID], [ARSalesPrice].[InventoryID], [ARSalesPrice].[CuryID], [ARSalesPrice].[UOM], [ARSalesPrice].[IsPromotionalPrice], [ARSalesPrice].[EffectiveDate], [ARSalesPrice].[SalesPrice], [ARSalesPrice].[TaxID], [ARSalesPrice].[BreakQty], [ARSalesPrice].[ExpirationDate], [ARSalesPrice].[tstamp], [ARSalesPrice].[CreatedByID], [ARSalesPrice].[CreatedByScreenID], [ARSalesPrice].[CreatedDateTime], [ARSalesPrice].[LastModifiedByID], [ARSalesPrice].[LastModifiedByScreenID], [ARSalesPrice].[LastModifiedDateTime], [InventoryItem].[InventoryID], [InventoryItem].[InventoryCD], [InventoryItem].[Descr], [InventoryItem].[ItemClassID], [InventoryItem].[ItemStatus], [InventoryItem].[ItemType], [InventoryItem].[ValMethod], [InventoryItem].[TaxCategoryID], [InventoryItem].[BaseUnit], [InventoryItem].[SalesUnit], [InventoryItem].[PurchaseUnit], [InventoryItem].[Commisionable], [InventoryItem].[ReasonCodeSubID], [InventoryItem].[SalesAcctID], [InventoryItem].[SalesSubID], [InventoryItem].[InvtAcctID], [InventoryItem].[InvtSubID], [InventoryItem].[COGSAcctID], [InventoryItem].[COGSSubID], [InventoryItem].[DiscAcctID], [InventoryItem].[DiscSubID], [InventoryItem].[StdCstRevAcctID], [InventoryItem].[StdCstRevSubID], [InventoryItem].[StdCstVarAcctID], [InventoryItem].[StdCstVarSubID], [InventoryItem].[PPVAcctID], [InventoryItem].[PPVSubID], [InventoryItem].[POAccrualAcctID], [InventoryItem].[POAccrualSubID], [InventoryItem].[LCVarianceAcctID], [InventoryItem].[LCVarianceSubID], [InventoryItem].[DeferralAcctID], [InventoryItem].[DeferralSubID], [InventoryItem].[LastSiteID], [InventoryItem].[LastStdCost], [InventoryItem].[PendingStdCost], [InventoryItem].[PendingStdCostDate], [InventoryItem].[StdCost], [InventoryItem].[StdCostDate], [InventoryItem].[BasePrice], [InventoryItem].[BaseWeight], [InventoryItem].[BaseVolume], [InventoryItem].[BaseItemWeight], [InventoryItem].[BaseItemVolume], [InventoryItem].[WeightUOM], [InventoryItem].[VolumeUOM], [InventoryItem].[PackSeparately], [InventoryItem].[PackageOption], [InventoryItem].[PreferredVendorID], [InventoryItem].[PreferredVendorLocationID], [InventoryItem].[DefaultSubItemID], [InventoryItem].[DefaultSubItemOnEntry], [InventoryItem].[DfltSiteID], [InventoryItem].[DfltShipLocationID], [InventoryItem].[DfltReceiptLocationID], [InventoryItem].[ProductWorkgroupID], [InventoryItem].[ProductManagerID], [InventoryItem].[PriceWorkgroupID], [InventoryItem].[PriceManagerID], [InventoryItem].[StkItem], (SELECT TOP (1) ([INItemClass].[NegQty])  FROM INItemClass INItemClass WHERE (INItemClass.CompanyID = 3) AND INItemClass.DeletedDatabaseRecord = 0 AND  ( [INItemClass].[ItemClassID] = [InventoryItem].[ItemClassID]) ORDER BY [INItemClass].[NegQty]), [InventoryItem].[LotSerClassID], [InventoryItem].[LotSerNumVal], [InventoryItem].[PostClassID], [InventoryItem].[DeferredCode], [InventoryItem].[DefaultTerm], [InventoryItem].[DefaultTermUOM], [InventoryItem].[PriceClassID], [InventoryItem].[IsSplitted], [InventoryItem].[UseParentSubID], [InventoryItem].[KitItem], [InventoryItem].[MinGrossProfitPct], [InventoryItem].[NonStockReceipt], [InventoryItem].[NonStockShip], [InventoryItem].[CompletePOLine], [InventoryItem].[ABCCodeID], [InventoryItem].[ABCCodeIsFixed], [InventoryItem].[MovementClassID], [InventoryItem].[MovementClassIsFixed], [InventoryItem].[MarkupPct], [InventoryItem].[RecPrice], [InventoryItem].[ImageUrl], [InventoryItem].[NoteID], NULL, NULL, NULL, [InventoryItem].[CreatedByID], [InventoryItem].[CreatedByScreenID], [InventoryItem].[CreatedDateTime], [InventoryItem].[LastModifiedByID], [InventoryItem].[LastModifiedByScreenID], [InventoryItem].[LastModifiedDateTime], [InventoryItem].[GroupMask], [InventoryItem].[CycleID], [InventoryItem].[tstamp], [InventoryItem].[IsRUTROTDeductible], [InventoryItem].[Body], [InventoryItem].[RUTROTType], [InventoryItem].[RUTROTItemType], [InventoryItem].[RUTROTWorkType], ( ( ( [InventoryItem].[UsrPartNumber] +  N'' : '') +  [InventoryItem].[UsrBrand])), [InventoryItem].[UsrSISupersededBy], [InventoryItem].[UsrPartNumber], [InventoryItem].[UsrBrand], [InventoryItem].[UsrFrgnName], [InventoryItem].[UsrSIPackSize], [InventoryItem].[UsrSICountryOfOrigin], [InventoryItem].[UsrSILength], [InventoryItem].[UsrSIWidth], [InventoryItem].[UsrSIHeight], [InventoryItem].[UsrSIAssocPartNumber], [InventoryItem].[UsrSISpecs], [InventoryItem].[UsrSIFactoryPartnumber], [InventoryItem].[UsrSIItemMovementClass], (SELECT TOP (1) ([INItemClass].[UsrSIMainGroup])  FROM INItemClass INItemClass WHERE (INItemClass.CompanyID = 3) AND INItemClass.DeletedDatabaseRecord = 0 AND  ( [INItemClass].[ItemClassID] = [InventoryItem].[ItemClassID]) ORDER BY [INItemClass].[UsrSIMainGroup]), [InventoryItem].[UsrSIPrintDescr] FROM ARSalesPrice ARSalesPrice LEFT JOIN InventoryItem InventoryItem ON (InventoryItem.CompanyID = 3) AND InventoryItem.DeletedDatabaseRecord = 0 AND ( [InventoryItem].[InventoryID] = [ARSalesPrice].[InventoryID]) WHERE (ARSalesPrice.CompanyID = 3) AND  [InventoryItem].[ItemStatus] <> N''IN'' AND [InventoryItem].[ItemStatus] <> N''DE'' AND ( @P0 = N''A'' OR [ARSalesPrice].[PriceType] = @P1) AND ( [ARSalesPrice].[CustomerID] = @P2 OR [ARSalesPrice].[CustPriceClassID] = @P3 OR @P4 IS NULL) AND ( [ARSalesPrice].[InventoryID] = @P5 OR @P6 IS NULL) AND ( ( ( [ARSalesPrice].[EffectiveDate] <= @P7 OR [ARSalesPrice].[EffectiveDate] IS NULL) AND ( [ARSalesPrice].[ExpirationDate] >= @P8 OR [ARSalesPrice].[ExpirationDate] IS NULL)) OR @P9 IS NULL) AND ( @P10 IS NULL OR @P11 = [InventoryItem].[ItemClassID]) AND ( @P12 IS NULL OR @P13 = [InventoryItem].[PriceClassID]) AND ( @P14 IS NULL OR @P15 = [InventoryItem].[PriceManagerID]) AND ( @P16 = CONVERT(BIT, 0) OR [InventoryItem].[PriceWorkgroupID] IN (SELECT EPCompanyTreeMember.workGroupID FROM EPCompanyTreeMember EPCompanyTreeMember WHERE (EPCompanyTreeMember.CompanyID = 3) AND EPCompanyTreeMember.userID= CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ''b5344897-037e-4d58-b5c3-1bdfd0f47bf9'')  AND EPCompanyTreeMember.active=1)) AND ( @P17 IS NULL OR @P18 = [InventoryItem].[PriceWorkgroupID]) ORDER BY (SELECT TOP (1) inventoryCD FROM InventoryItem InventoryItemExt WHERE (InventoryItemExt.CompanyID = 3) AND InventoryItemExt.DeletedDatabaseRecord = 0 AND [InventoryItemExt].[inventoryID] = [ARSalesPrice].[InventoryID]), CASE WHEN [ARSalesPrice].[PriceType] = ''B'' THEN ''Base'' WHEN [ARSalesPrice].[PriceType] = ''C'' THEN ''Customer'' WHEN [ARSalesPrice].[PriceType] = ''P'' THEN ''Customer Price Class'' END, [ARSalesPrice].[UOM], [ARSalesPrice].[BreakQty], [ARSalesPrice].[EffectiveDate], [ARSalesPrice].[RecordID] OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) /* AR.20.20.00 */' 
, 
N'@P0 char(1),@P1 char(1),@P2 varchar(30),@P3 varchar(30),@P4 varchar(30),@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 smalldatetime,@P8 smalldatetime,@P9 smalldatetime,@P10 varchar(10),@P11 varchar(10),@P12 varchar(10),@P13 varchar(10),@P14 uniqueidentifier,@P15 uniqueidentifier,@P16 bit,@P17 int,@P18 int'
, 
@P0='A', 
@P1='A', 
@P2=NULL, 
@P3=NULL, 
@P4=NULL, 
@P5=NULL, 
@P6=NULL, 
@P7=NULL, 
@P8=NULL, 
@P9=NULL, 
@P10=NULL, 
@P11=NULL, 
@P12=NULL, 
@P13=NULL, 
@P14=NULL, 
@P15=NULL, 
@P16=0, 
@P17=NULL, 
@P18=NULL
```

Takes several minutes to process.

Same in normal SQL

```
DECLARE @P0  CHAR(1), 
        @P1  CHAR(1), 
        @P2  VARCHAR(30), 
        @P3  VARCHAR(30), 
        @P4  VARCHAR(30), 
        @P5  INT, 
        @P6  INT, 
        @P7  SMALLDATETIME, 
        @P8  SMALLDATETIME, 
        @P9  SMALLDATETIME, 
        @P10 VARCHAR(10), 
        @P11 VARCHAR(10), 
        @P12 VARCHAR(10), 
        @P13 VARCHAR(10), 
        @P14 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
        @P15 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
        @P16 BIT, 
        @P17 INT, 
        @P18 INT 

SET @P0='A' 
SET @P1='A' 
SET @P2=NULL 
SET @P3=NULL 
SET @P4=NULL 
SET @P5=NULL 
SET @P6=NULL 
SET @P7=NULL 
SET @P8=NULL 
SET @P9=NULL 
SET @P10=NULL 
SET @P11=NULL 
SET @P12=NULL 
SET @P13=NULL 
SET @P14=NULL 
SET @P15=NULL 
SET @P16=0 
SET @P17=NULL 
SET @P18=NULL 

SELECT TOP (27) [arsalesprice].[recordid], 
                [arsalesprice].[pricetype], 
                [arsalesprice].[custpriceclassid], 
                [arsalesprice].[customerid], 
                [arsalesprice].[inventoryid], 
                [arsalesprice].[curyid], 
                [arsalesprice].[uom], 
                [arsalesprice].[ispromotionalprice], 
                [arsalesprice].[effectivedate], 
                [arsalesprice].[salesprice], 
                [arsalesprice].[taxid], 
                [arsalesprice].[breakqty], 
                [arsalesprice].[expirationdate], 
                [arsalesprice].[tstamp], 
                [arsalesprice].[createdbyid], 
                [arsalesprice].[createdbyscreenid], 
                [arsalesprice].[createddatetime], 
                [arsalesprice].[lastmodifiedbyid], 
                [arsalesprice].[lastmodifiedbyscreenid], 
                [arsalesprice].[lastmodifieddatetime], 
                [inventoryitem].[inventoryid], 
                [inventoryitem].[inventorycd], 
                [inventoryitem].[descr], 
                [inventoryitem].[itemclassid], 
                [inventoryitem].[itemstatus], 
                [inventoryitem].[itemtype], 
                [inventoryitem].[valmethod], 
                [inventoryitem].[taxcategoryid], 
                [inventoryitem].[baseunit], 
                [inventoryitem].[salesunit], 
                [inventoryitem].[purchaseunit], 
                [inventoryitem].[commisionable], 
                [inventoryitem].[reasoncodesubid], 
                [inventoryitem].[salesacctid], 
                [inventoryitem].[salessubid], 
                [inventoryitem].[invtacctid], 
                [inventoryitem].[invtsubid], 
                [inventoryitem].[cogsacctid], 
                [inventoryitem].[cogssubid], 
                [inventoryitem].[discacctid], 
                [inventoryitem].[discsubid], 
                [inventoryitem].[stdcstrevacctid], 
                [inventoryitem].[stdcstrevsubid], 
                [inventoryitem].[stdcstvaracctid], 
                [inventoryitem].[stdcstvarsubid], 
                [inventoryitem].[ppvacctid], 
                [inventoryitem].[ppvsubid], 
                [inventoryitem].[poaccrualacctid], 
                [inventoryitem].[poaccrualsubid], 
                [inventoryitem].[lcvarianceacctid], 
                [inventoryitem].[lcvariancesubid], 
                [inventoryitem].[deferralacctid], 
                [inventoryitem].[deferralsubid], 
                [inventoryitem].[lastsiteid], 
                [inventoryitem].[laststdcost], 
                [inventoryitem].[pendingstdcost], 
                [inventoryitem].[pendingstdcostdate], 
                [inventoryitem].[stdcost], 
                [inventoryitem].[stdcostdate], 
                [inventoryitem].[baseprice], 
                [inventoryitem].[baseweight], 
                [inventoryitem].[basevolume], 
                [inventoryitem].[baseitemweight], 
                [inventoryitem].[baseitemvolume], 
                [inventoryitem].[weightuom], 
                [inventoryitem].[volumeuom], 
                [inventoryitem].[packseparately], 
                [inventoryitem].[packageoption], 
                [inventoryitem].[preferredvendorid], 
                [inventoryitem].[preferredvendorlocationid], 
                [inventoryitem].[defaultsubitemid], 
                [inventoryitem].[defaultsubitemonentry], 
                [inventoryitem].[dfltsiteid], 
                [inventoryitem].[dfltshiplocationid], 
                [inventoryitem].[dfltreceiptlocationid], 
                [inventoryitem].[productworkgroupid], 
                [inventoryitem].[productmanagerid], 
                [inventoryitem].[priceworkgroupid], 
                [inventoryitem].[pricemanagerid], 
                [inventoryitem].[stkitem], 
                (SELECT TOP (1) ( [initemclass].[negqty] ) 
                 FROM   initemclass INItemClass 
                 WHERE  ( initemclass.companyid = 3 ) 
                        AND initemclass.deleteddatabaserecord = 0 
                        AND ( [initemclass].[itemclassid] = 
                              [inventoryitem].[itemclassid] ) 
                 ORDER  BY [initemclass].[negqty]), 
                [inventoryitem].[lotserclassid], 
                [inventoryitem].[lotsernumval], 
                [inventoryitem].[postclassid], 
                [inventoryitem].[deferredcode], 
                [inventoryitem].[defaultterm], 
                [inventoryitem].[defaulttermuom], 
                [inventoryitem].[priceclassid], 
                [inventoryitem].[issplitted], 
                [inventoryitem].[useparentsubid], 
                [inventoryitem].[kititem], 
                [inventoryitem].[mingrossprofitpct], 
                [inventoryitem].[nonstockreceipt], 
                [inventoryitem].[nonstockship], 
                [inventoryitem].[completepoline], 
                [inventoryitem].[abccodeid], 
                [inventoryitem].[abccodeisfixed], 
                [inventoryitem].[movementclassid], 
                [inventoryitem].[movementclassisfixed], 
                [inventoryitem].[markuppct], 
                [inventoryitem].[recprice], 
                [inventoryitem].[imageurl], 
                [inventoryitem].[noteid], 
                NULL, 
                NULL, 
                NULL, 
                [inventoryitem].[createdbyid], 
                [inventoryitem].[createdbyscreenid], 
                [inventoryitem].[createddatetime], 
                [inventoryitem].[lastmodifiedbyid], 
                [inventoryitem].[lastmodifiedbyscreenid], 
                [inventoryitem].[lastmodifieddatetime], 
                [inventoryitem].[groupmask], 
                [inventoryitem].[cycleid], 
                [inventoryitem].[tstamp], 
                [inventoryitem].[isrutrotdeductible], 
                [inventoryitem].[body], 
                [inventoryitem].[rutrottype], 
                [inventoryitem].[rutrotitemtype], 
                [inventoryitem].[rutrotworktype], 
                (( ( [inventoryitem].[usrpartnumber] + ' : ' ) + 
                   [inventoryitem].[usrbrand] )), 
                [inventoryitem].[usrsisupersededby], 
                [inventoryitem].[usrpartnumber], 
                [inventoryitem].[usrbrand], 
                [inventoryitem].[usrfrgnname], 
                [inventoryitem].[usrsipacksize], 
                [inventoryitem].[usrsicountryoforigin], 
                [inventoryitem].[usrsilength], 
                [inventoryitem].[usrsiwidth], 
                [inventoryitem].[usrsiheight], 
                [inventoryitem].[usrsiassocpartnumber], 
                [inventoryitem].[usrsispecs], 
                [inventoryitem].[usrsifactorypartnumber], 
                [inventoryitem].[usrsiitemmovementclass], 
                (SELECT TOP (1) ( [initemclass].[usrsimaingroup] ) 
                 FROM   initemclass INItemClass 
                 WHERE  ( initemclass.companyid = 3 ) 
                        AND initemclass.deleteddatabaserecord = 0 
                        AND ( [initemclass].[itemclassid] = 
                              [inventoryitem].[itemclassid] ) 
                 ORDER  BY [initemclass].[usrsimaingroup]), 
                [inventoryitem].[usrsiprintdescr] 
FROM   arsalesprice ARSalesPrice 
       LEFT JOIN inventoryitem InventoryItem 
              ON ( inventoryitem.companyid = 3 ) 
                 AND inventoryitem.deleteddatabaserecord = 0 
                 AND ( [inventoryitem].[inventoryid] = 
                       [arsalesprice].[inventoryid] ) 
WHERE  ( arsalesprice.companyid = 3 ) 
       AND [inventoryitem].[itemstatus] <> 'IN' 
       AND [inventoryitem].[itemstatus] <> 'DE' 
       AND ( @P0 = N'A' 
              OR [arsalesprice].[pricetype] = @P1 ) 
       AND ( [arsalesprice].[customerid] = @P2 
              OR [arsalesprice].[custpriceclassid] = @P3 
              OR @P4 IS NULL ) 
       AND ( [arsalesprice].[inventoryid] = @P5 
              OR @P6 IS NULL ) 
       AND ( ( ( [arsalesprice].[effectivedate] <= @P7 
                  OR [arsalesprice].[effectivedate] IS NULL ) 
               AND ( [arsalesprice].[expirationdate] >= @P8 
                      OR [arsalesprice].[expirationdate] IS NULL ) ) 
              OR @P9 IS NULL ) 
       AND ( @P10 IS NULL 
              OR @P11 = [inventoryitem].[itemclassid] ) 
       AND ( @P12 IS NULL 
              OR @P13 = [inventoryitem].[priceclassid] ) 
       AND ( @P14 IS NULL 
              OR @P15 = [inventoryitem].[pricemanagerid] ) 
       AND ( @P16 = CONVERT(BIT, 0) 
              OR [inventoryitem].[priceworkgroupid] IN 
                     (SELECT epcompanytreemember.workgroupid 
                                                        FROM 
                     epcompanytreemember EPCompanyTreeMember 
                                                        WHERE  ( 
                     epcompanytreemember.companyid = 3 ) 
                                                               AND 
                     epcompanytreemember.userid = 
                     CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
                     'b5344897-037e-4d58-b5c3-1bdfd0f47bf9') 
                                     AND 
                     epcompanytreemember.active = 1) ) 
       AND ( @P17 IS NULL 
              OR @P18 = [inventoryitem].[priceworkgroupid] ) 
ORDER  BY (SELECT TOP (1) inventorycd 
           FROM   inventoryitem InventoryItemExt 
           WHERE  ( InventoryItemExt.companyid = 3 ) 
                  AND InventoryItemExt.deleteddatabaserecord = 0 
                  AND [InventoryItemExt].[inventoryid] = 
                      [arsalesprice].[inventoryid]), 
          CASE 
            WHEN [arsalesprice].[pricetype] = 'B' THEN 'Base' 
            WHEN [arsalesprice].[pricetype] = 'C' THEN 'Customer' 
            WHEN [arsalesprice].[pricetype] = 'P' THEN 'Customer Price Class' 
          END, 
          [arsalesprice].[uom], 
          [arsalesprice].[breakqty], 
          [arsalesprice].[effectivedate], 
          [arsalesprice].[recordid] 
OPTION(optimize FOR unknown) /* AR.20.20.00 */
```

Just takes 2-3 seconds to run.

I tried clearing the query plan after adding indexes. still issue persists.
sp_executesql  is generated by a framework and I am trying to optimize that query result. so is there anything i can do to make it run faster?
Any help?

Comment: what if you replace `OPTION(optimize FOR unknown)` with `OPTION(recompile)` ? Any differences?

Comment: Having so many optional parameters can lead to an inefficient execution plan. This may be a case where dynamic sql beats the generic statement. Try build the sql statement dynamically in a VARCHAR without the conditionals for a parameter that is NULL, see if execution is any faster.

Comment: @CeOnSql, Actually i tried that and there is difference(runs in less than 10 secs). But any way this query is generated by a framework and so i am unable to change it for now.

Comment: @TT. as mentioned in the above comment, it is from a framework so I cant change that dyanmic query for now. is there any other way i can make the Sp_executesql work in a faster way?

Comment: It's hard to say what you can do at all then, because the framework is the limiting factor.